# Xperia Z3 Compact Phone do not display recovery/bootloader console

Tags: android, sony, fastboot

I was trying to root my device (Xperia Z3 Compact) as instructed here:

[DooMLoRD's CWM-Based Recovery Console](http://forum.xda-developers.com/z3/orig-development/d66xx-cwm-based-recovery-6-0-4-7-root-t2890116)

Somewhere in between, a mistake was made and being the novice that I am, I can't seem to undo it.
I also have no idea what happened, but if what I understood online is right, I screwed up the bootloader which made the recovery console unavailable.

Here is screenshot on Emma:

[image]

Here are the steps I made on the console:

[image]

Also, the phone makes some sort of nice sound, not a beep, although I can't identify it and the screen is always black.

I would pretty much appreciate all the help, with the things I've done, I've pretty much voided the warranty (I think) so I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: do you correct apply step #4 from this manual http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/flash-tool/use-the-flash-tool-for-xperia-devices/ while trying to connect?

Comment: do you able to connect to device with `fastboot`?

Comment: Yes, I did both. The first screenshot show my device (D5833). The second screenshot shows the custom boot loader being written to the device. After I did the steps on the second screenshot, the phone won't work, and gets stuck on the black screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We advise users to check [supported devices](http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/flash-tool/supported_phones/) at Developer World.

The D5833 is now added as a supported device, and I hope it will appear as an available service next time you connect your Z3 compact.

Best regards
Carl
Sony developer support

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, by rooting device you've lost warranty.

I've faced with fact it's not to easy run Recovery Console while booting device. Sometimes I had to push to volume control buttons very long and fast for achieving result.

Please check is device seen by `fastboot` now.

I believe if bootloader is really broken you have to take your device to the service. Guys from service should be able to recover it by JTAG.

Comment: Yup, the device is seen by fastboot. It cost me a lot to buy the phone and I don't think I can afford it just yet to pay for its repair. I'll push my luck and fix the phone because of my stupid mistake. Thanks for answer and advice.

Comment: I had similar issue with my Xperia Z. Seems like I've flashed it with wrong image. Device started to boot but stuck while booting. My luck device was seen by `Emma`. Thus `Emma` helped me in that case. But be aware if you will recover by `Emma` you will lose all your data on the device. 

Any way if device is seen by `fastboot` you always can re-flash with some other image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've already flashed a custom kernel.

Key sequence for entering recovery program may change depending on the kernel being flashed. So for my Xperia P I've had to press the power button repeatedly until I get into CWM recovery.

To switch into **fastboot** : press and hold the volume Up button, and plug in the USB cable; the notification LED will light up Blue

**flash mode**: press and hold the volume Down button, and plug in the USB cable